# Connect to a FTPS server within shell script

Tags: shell, ftp

I'm trying to connect to a FTPS (explicit TLS FTP) server within a shell script and i'm kinda confused.
I tried using the regular FTP command, but i get 534 error "policy requires SSL" and 504 "Security mechanism not implemented"

```
ftp -inuv myhost
```

Returns 504 then

```
quote USER myuser
```

Returns 534

I also tried sftp  but i get "couldn't read packet: connection reset by peer".
That damn peer is making my life a nightmare since IRC ;)

```
sftp myuser@myhost:mydirectory/ -P21
```

Connexion reset by peer and it says it can't connect to port 22, which is weird since i specified port 21...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a diference between ftps and sftp : sftp is ftp over ssh, so in your case you cannot use sftp. ftps is ftp that use ssl/tls

You need an ftp client that manages TLS, for instance http://lftp.yar.ru/ (found on the net)

Comment: I understood that SFTP and FTPS were different but i somehow hoped that i could handle TLS with the bundled ftp applications on my system.
Thanks, i'll try that and update this post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, after a lot of reading and trying, it works like a charm in a single command :

Comment: Could you give the command, it may be useful for someone else

Comment: It actually worked just like that :
export SSHPASS=MYPASS

/usr/local/bin/sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - LOGIN@HOST << !
DO FTP STUFF HERE
bye
!